# timeScale=0 doesnt stop all prefabs in unity

Tags: unity, unityscript

As expected timeScale=0 can be used for stopping the game or pausing but when i make timeScale equal to 0 some prefabs still move and they can shoot bullets but addforce doesnt effect to bullets and they stop there. I know i can fix the problem on handling code of my prefabs but they are a lot. is there a good way to do the trick in my game? 
thank you for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the exception of `FixedUpdate`, which isn't called with `timeScale = 0`, all other Update methods will get called, and have their code executed.

So setting `Time.timeScale = 0` doesn't necessarily guarantee an object won't move, but if you're keeping your game framerate independent through the use of `Time.deltaTime` then `timeScale = 0` should stop most things.

For example, the following would stop movement, because if `Time.timeScale` is `0`, then `Time.deltaTime` would return `0`, resulting in no translation.

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
```

Also, physics aren't updated either when `timeScale = 0`. See http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html for more info.

But ultimately, if you need something to stop (both in terms of movement and executing other actions) you'll need to add a check to your Update methods that return on pause.

```
void Update() {
    if (IsGamePaused) {
        return;
    }
    // All other script logic...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, you have to check if you're paused or not in **every single script**, because setting the time scale to zero won't pause the execution of all your script (which is great, of course... to handle things the user can do **while** in pause for exemple).